# More complex IF statements within MySQL query

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I asked a related question a week ago, but here's another problem I'm facing.  I feel like such a noob, but I guess it's better to ask and learn than never learn.

Here are my three tables:

Fighters Table

```
fighter_id, name
```

Events Table

```
event_id, event_name, event_date
```

Fights Table

```
fight_id, fighter_a, fighter_b, winner, method, event
```

So in the fights table, fighter_a, fighter_b, and winner are integers that correspond to fighter_id in the Fighters table.

I'm basically on a page retrieving data based on fighter_id.

I'm trying to create rows with each fight of that fighter that includes his opponent's name, result (win, loss, draw, or nc), method, event_name, and event_date.  If it's a Draw or No Contest, it'll say Draw or No Contest in Method column, while winner will be NULL.

I was looking at these MySQL IF statements, and created what would be the appropriate criteria for determining whether a fighter won, lost, got a draw, or no contest.  It doesn't seem like these statements can be used in a PHP mysql_query, but at least it gives you an idea of criteria.  I know I have to inner join these 3 tables together, but I'm not sure how to determine winner/loser/etc... because fighter_a or fighter_b can be a winner, or neither could be.  I don't know how to approach these IF statements in MySQL query.

```
IF winner IS NOT NULL AND winner=fighter_id THEN SET record='win';
ELSEIF winner IS NOT NULL AND winner<>fighter_id THEN SET record='loss';
ELSEIF winner IS NULL AND method='Draw' THEN SET record='draw';
ELSEIF winner IS NULL AND method='No Contest' THEN SET record='no contest';
ELSE SET record='';
ELSE IF;
```

I'm trying to get a result in a table that look something like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedor_Emelianenko#Mixed_martial_arts_record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe you would want to use a CASE statement to determine the result. The fighters will require a join, similar to this:

```
select 
    fight_id,
    CASE
      WHEN winner is not null and winner=fighter_id then 'win'
      WHEN winner is not null and winner<>fighter_id then 'loss'
      WHEN winner is null and method='Draw' then 'draw'
      WHEN winner is null and method = 'No Contest' then 'no contest'
      ELSE ''
    END as match_result,
    participant.name 'participant',
    opponent.name 'opponent'
FROM fights
    INNER JOIN fighters as participant on participant.fighter_id = fights.fighter_a
    INNER JOIN fighters as oppoent on opponent.fighter_id = fights.fighter_b
```

Comment: Great!  That will work perfectly.  Any ideas how I can determine the opponent?  There is fighter_a and fighter_b columns.  One of those is $fighter_id (the one you're looking up) and the other is his opponent.  I need to do like if fighter_a <> $fighter_id OR fighter_b <> $fighter_id AS opponent?

Comment: No, you would join the fighters table. I'll revise my answer a bit. Feel free to upvote/accept if my answer helps you.

Comment: Ok great.  I'll give it a shot and will respond if I run into any other issues.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok so something is still not jiving quite right.  I think it might be because opponent could be fighter_a or fighter_b.  Opponent won't always necessarily be fighter_b.  I added a line at the end to find those fighter's fights like so:
`WHERE fighter_a=$fighter_id OR fighter_b=$fighter_id` 

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I need to see the rest of your code to help you any further. Want to open a new question?

Comment: Yea, let me put my thoughts together and organize it better and cleaner. New question makes more sense.  Thanks!