# Complex IF statement with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database, relational

This is a continuation of [this question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989796/more-complex-if-statements-within-mysql-query).

Here are my three tables:

Fighters Table

```
fighter_id |  name
-----------------------
1          | John
2          | Steve
3          | Bill
4          | Bobby
```

Events Table

```
event_id  |  event_name  |  event_date
-------------------------------------------
1          | MMA         |  01/01/2010
2          | Cool        |  02/20/2010
3          | Yeaa!       |  04/15/2010
```

Fights Table

```
fight_id  |  fighter_a  |  fighter_b  |  winner  |  method  |  event
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1           |  2          |  1       | Sub      | 1
2         | 4           |  1          |  4       | KO       | 2
3         | 1           |  3          |  NULL    | Draw     | 3
```

Result trying to get

```
result  |  opponent  |  method  |  event  |  date        
----------------------------------------------------------
Draw    | Bill       |  Draw    |  Yeaa!  |  04/15/2010  
Loss    | Bobby      |  KO      |  Cool   |  02/20/2010 
Win     | Steve      |  Sub     |  MMA    |  01/01/2010
```

So in the fights table, fighter_a, fighter_b, and winner are integers that correspond to fighter_id in the Fighters table.

I'm basically on a page retrieving data based on fighter_id ($fighter_id).

I'm trying to create rows with each fight of that fighter that includes his opponent's name, result (win, loss, draw, or nc), method, event_name, and event_date. The challenge is that a winner can be in either fighter_a or fighter_b.  It's not always in the same column.  I appreciate any help I can get.

```
select 
    fight_id,
    CASE
      WHEN winner is not null and winner=fighter_id then 'win'
      WHEN winner is not null and winner<>fighter_id then 'loss'
      WHEN winner is null and method='Draw' then 'draw'
      WHEN winner is null and method = 'No Contest' then 'no contest'
      ELSE ''
    END as match_result,
    participant.name 'participant',
    opponent.name 'opponent'
FROM fights
    INNER JOIN fighters as participant on participant.fighter_id = fights.fighter_a
    INNER JOIN fighters as oppoent on opponent.fighter_id = fights.fighter_b
WHERE 
    fighter_a=$fighter_id OR fighter_b=$fighter_id
ORDER BY
    event_date DESC
```

Comment: There is no join with Events table. How are you ordering by event_date?

Comment: Ugh, yea sorry.  This is a pain.  Are my three main tables setup correctly? It seems like a PITA to retrieve this data now. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subselect with conditionals to switch the fighter_id you're looking for to column_a if it's in column_b, that way, it simplifies your operations and joins in the outer query:

```
SELECT
    (
        CASE
            WHEN a.winner = a.f_a THEN 'Win'
            WHEN a.winner = a.f_b THEN 'Loss'
            WHEN a.winner IS NULL THEN a.method
        END
    ) AS result,
    b.name AS opponent,
    a.method AS method,
    c.event_name AS event,
    c.event_date AS date
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            IF(fighter_b = $fighter_id, fighter_b, fighter_a) AS f_a,
            IF(fighter_b = $fighter_id, fighter_a, fighter_b) AS f_b,
            winner,
            method,
            event
        FROM 
            fights
        WHERE
            $fighter_id IN (fighter_a, fighter_b)
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    fighters b ON a.f_b = b.fighter_id
INNER JOIN
    events c ON a.event = c.event_id
ORDER BY
    c.event_date DESC
```

Also, if the winner field is null, then just echo the method field. That way, when you want to add yet another type of method where winner is null to your system, you don't have to keep tacking on more conditional checks to your `CASE` statement.

Comment: Thanks, this returns `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE ) AS result, b.name AS opponent, a.method AS method, c.' at line 7`

Comment: Okay fixed. Try now, `END CASE` supposedly is supposed to be just `END`.

Comment: Oh man you rock! Thanks a lot man. And everyone else in this thread. It's so friggin hard to visualize this. I'll keep on trying to learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just modify you `CASE` statements to match with `$fighter_id`.

So your `CASE` statements would be  -

```
select fight_id,
       CASE
           WHEN winner is not null and winner = f.fighter_id then 'win'
           WHEN winner is not null and winner <> f.fighter_id then 'loss'
           WHEN winner is null and method='Draw' then 'draw'
           WHEN winner is null and method = 'No Contest' then 'no contest'
           ELSE ''
        END as match_result,
        f.name AS participant,
        (SELECT o.name FROM fighters o WHERE o.fighter_id = IF(f.fighter_id = fs.fighter_a, fs.fighter_b, fs.fighter_a)) AS opponent
FROM fights fs,
     fighters f
WHERE f.fighter_id = $fighter_id
AND (fs.fighter_a = f.fighter_id OR fs.fighter_b = f.fighter_id)
```

Comment: Hmm I get a SQL error `Table 'mma.fighter' doesn't exist`. Note, mma is the name of the db.  Are none of the original tables supposed to be in FROM?

Comment: Had a typo. Had written `fighter` instead of `fighters`.

Comment: Now I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fighter-detail.php on line 124`

This is how I'm trying to pull info with PHP.  Line 124 is echo match_result.

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_all_fighter_fights)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row->match_result . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}`

Comment: @zen you're getting that error because $row isn't an object, but you're using object syntax to try to get match_result from it. The proper syntax for an associative array is `$row['match_result']` .

Comment: Ahh I see.  That indeed fixed it. Hmm, I need to read up on the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN winner = participant_id THEN 'Win'
            WHEN winner = opponent_id then 'Loss'
            ELSE method
       END AS result, fighters.name AS opponent, method, event_name, event_date
  FROM fights
  INNER JOIN fighters ON fighter_id = opponent_id
  INNER JOIN events ON event = event_id
  WHERE participant_id = $fighter_id
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN winner = participant_id THEN 'Loss'
            WHEN winner = opponent_id then 'Win'
            ELSE method
       END AS result, fighters.name AS opponent, method, event_name, event_date
  FROM fights
  INNER JOIN fighters ON fighter_id = participant_id
  INNER JOIN events ON event = event_id
  WHERE opponent_id = $fighter_id
ORDER BY event_date DESC
```

Comment: This returns `Unknown column 'participant_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @zen Sorry, I misread the question; `participant_id` should probably be `fighter_a` and `opponent_id` should be `fighter_b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN winner is not null and winner=fighter_id then 'win'
      WHEN winner is not null and winner<>fighter_id then 'loss'
      WHEN winner is null and method='Draw' then 'draw'
      WHEN winner is null and method = 'No Contest' then 'no contest'
      ELSE ''
    END result,
    f2.name opponent,
    method,
    event_name event,
    event_date date
FROM fights f1
INNER JOIN fighters f2
ON f1.fighter_b = f2.fighter_id
INNER JOIN events e
ON e.event_id = f1.event
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: This also returns `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fighter-detail.php on line 128`.  Line 128 is just fetching rows out of an array with `$row->result`