# Mini PHP search engine that searches two tables

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to create a mini PHP search engine that simply searches in two different tables and displays results of one table under another. But I'm getting an error.  Here's where I setup the queries.

```
$var = $_GET['q']; 
$trimmed = trim($var);
$get_fighters = "
SELECT * 
FROM fighters 
WHERE name LIKE '%$trimmed%' 
ORDER BY name ASC";
$get_events = "
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE event_name LIKE '%$trimmed%' 
ORDER BY date DESC";
$search_result_fighters = mysql_query($get_fighters); 
$search_result_events = mysql_query($get_events); 
$check_results_fighters = mysql_num_rows($search_result_fighters); 
$check_results_events = mysql_num_rows($search_result_events);
```

Here's where I return fighters (which works)

```
if ($check_results_fighters == 0) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='6'>" . "No Fighters Found." . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($check_results_fighters != 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result_fighters)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    } 
}
```

And here's where I return events, but it doesn't work.  I get error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 30

```
if ($check_results_events == 0) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='6'>" . "No Events Found." . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($check_results_events != 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result_events)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" .  $row['event_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    } 
}
```

Line 30 is simply this:

```
$check_results_events = mysql_num_rows($search_result_events);
```

Comment: Better read up about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) before you take this code any further, or you're going to get your server pwn3d

Comment: `trim()` will definitely not protect you against SQL Injection attacks. Use `mysql_real_escape_string(trim($var));` if you still insist on using the `mysql_*` functions. Better, learn [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and its support for [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Yea I'll start learning and switching to PDO.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the table structure in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006025/complex-if-statement-with-3-tables), 'date' is supposed to be 'event_date' in your events table:

```
$get_events = "
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE event_name LIKE '%$trimmed%' 
ORDER BY event_date DESC";
```

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you.  I need to get into the habit of checking mysql for errors as the guys above suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

That error is thrown where there was an error in your SQL query. A successful SQL query returns a resource which can be used as an argument to `mysql_num_rows()`. A failed SQL query returns a boolean `false` which is not a valid argument for `mysql_num_rows()`, hence the error.

Double check your table structure, field names, and SQL query.

For additional debugging, do this:

```
$search_result_events = mysql_query($yourQuery) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will output the error thrown by MySQL.

**Sidenotes**

There is no need to do

```
if ($check_results == 0) {
} 
// the if condition here is redundant, don't you agree?
else if ($check_results != 0) {
}
```

While the performance penalty of the extra comparison is very, very, very minute, it throws off someone who might read your code.

Also, please stop using the `mysql_` functions. [Here's a brilliant tutorial on PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). You should be using this.

Comment: Best advice is to NEVER assume a query succeeded, and ALWAYS check return values for failure. Even if the SQL syntax itself is perfectly valid, there's far too many OTHER reasons for a query to fail to NOT check for failure.